# Run time error in two dim array using pointers and malloc in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am a newbie and novice to C programming and learning pointers and implementation of 2-dimensional arrays using pointers. I am getting a runtime error while executing the following program which compiles without any complaint but crashes at run-time with the message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". If I run the program without using malloc(for dynamic memory allocation) it runs perfectly. I am using gcc compiler on Ubuntu linux.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define ROW 3
#define COL 3
main()
{
 int *arr[ROW];
 int i,j;
 arr[ROW] = (int *) malloc(COL * sizeof(int));  //dynamic memory allocation

 printf("\nEnter values\n\n");

 for(i=0;i<ROW;i++)
    {
     for(j=0;j<COL;j++)
         scanf("%d",(*(arr+i)+j));
     }


 printf("\nEntered values are\n");

 for(i=0;i<ROW;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<COL;j++)
          printf("\t%d",*(*(arr+i)+j));
          printf("\n");
     }
 printf("\n");
 }
```

The program crashes with the following message at run time:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The following version of the program (without malloc) executes perfectly without any error

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define ROW 3
#define COL 3
main()
{
int *arr[ROW][COL];
int i,j;

printf("\nEnter values\n\n");
for(i=0;i<ROW;i++)
   {
    for(j=0;j<COL;j++)
        scanf("%d",(*(arr+i)+j));
   }


 printf("\nEntered values are\n");

 for(i=0;i<ROW;i++)
    {
     for(j=0;j<COL;j++)
         printf("\t%d",*(*(arr+i)+j));
     printf("\n");
     }

 printf("\n");
 }
```

Comment: It would have been great with well indented code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code you are not allocating correctly your array. Here you are only allocating the last ROW/COL of your matrix, you should allocate this way:

```
for(i=0; i<ROW; ++i)
     arr[i] = (int *) malloc(COL * sizeof(int));
```

And by the way you should be aware that anything that has been allocated dynamically has to be desallocated. Ifnot you are getting a memory leaks:

```
for(i=0; i<ROW; ++i)
     free( arr[i] );
```

Comment: How stupid of me to allocate memory for only one row. I have made the changes and the program runs perfectly now. Thanks a ton :)  Should i use the code for freeing the memory at the end. What are the problems if i dont free memory at the end....isnt memory automatically freed when program execution ends

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your first segment of code is this line:

```
arr[ROW] = (int *) malloc(COL * sizeof(int));  //dynamic memory allocation
```

You have [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) everywhere. First, with `arr[ROW]` you access outside the bounds of the array. Second, if you want allocate a `ROW` number of pointers, then you need use a loop and store in `arr`.

```
for(i=0;i<ROW;i++)
arr[i]=malloc(COL * sizeof(int));
```

`free()` them once you are done with it and [don't cast the return value of malloc()](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html).

---

Your second program is not correct either. The array of pointers is not initialized at all. They pointers don't point valid memory locations. You need to allocate memory for *each* of the pointers or simply use a proper array like: `int arr[ROW][COL]`.